# HTML5 Canvas leaving pixel traces for small objects in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, game-engine

I'm pretty new to html5 canvas. With the help of a tutorial I was able to reproduce a version of Galaxian, and add some extra features to the game. The game renders with no issues in Chrome, but when using Firefox some of the elements leave pixel traces when moving across the canvas (see enemys' bullets in attached images as reference - Chrome Vs Firefox).

[image: Using Chrome]

[image: Using Firefox]

I noticed this only happens to the very small elements (if a change the bullet sprite for a bigger image, no traces are left). I'm using dirty rectangles to redraw every moving bullet:

```
    Bullet.prototype.draw = function(dt) {
      this.context.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      this.y -= this.speed * dt;
      if (this.alive)
        this.context.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y);
      }
    };
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something specific for other browsers when redrawing the sprite through clearRect and drawImage, has anyone faced a similar situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you rounding the coords to integer values? Not rounding will leave traces.

Comment: Oh wow! Yes, that completely fixes the issue... I kept scratching my head after so many changes I tried. Thanks for the help @Blindman67